# Testing Rails create controller action without touching the DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, mocking, stub

I want to test Rails `create` controller action  without touching the DB to save time. How to do this by following TDD best practices?

I have the following typical `create` controller action:

```
def create 
  @partner= Partner.new(params[:partner].permit(:name, :region, :contact))
  if @partner.save
    flash[:success] = 'Partner successfuly saved'
    redirect_to partner_url(@partner)
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

To properly test this works well without touching the DB I did the following:

```
specify 'successful create redirects to the show view' do
  @partner = FactoryGirl.build_stubbed(:partner)
  expect_any_instance_of(Partner).to receive(:save) do |_self|
      _self.id = @partner.id
      true
  end
  post :create, partner: @partner.attributes
  expect(response).to redirect_to partner_path(@partner.id)
end
```

This works well but to make it NOT touch DB I had to stub `save` and simulate it's behavior.

Is there a better/cleaner way of doing this?

Comment: Have you looked into using `@partner = FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:partner)` ?

Comment: Yes , `attributes_for` doesn't set and `:id` for the @partner so i can't use it. But I am looking more for a better/expert approach on how to do this because I want to use it all over my create tests.

Comment: But is your only use for the `:id` attribute to ensure that `@partner.save` returns `true`? If so, then are you really testing the right thing for a controller spec?

Comment: You have to stub save if you want to avoid hitting the database.  You'll probably have to stub a lot of other things as well.  Honestly though, how slow is your database?  There are advantages to actually seeing the queries go through.  Also - http://david.heinemeierhansson.com/2014/slow-database-test-fallacy.html

Comment: @TomLord:the `:id` does not get to the save because it is filtered by the `.permit`

Comment: @PhilipHallstrom: If I could stub lower then `.save` it would be perfect but i can't find where rails does the accessing of the DB after save. I get a 40% time increase on my machine by stubbing db everywhere so it is worth it. I am trying to set a workflow to always stub db. (like Fakeweb does this with stubbing http).

Comment: @Razor: I don't see how stubbing lower helps any.  You're still stubbing.  40% is a big jump.  What database? You could try an in memory SQLite database, although I don't like using alternate backends for testing than production.